# Check Ubuntu version history

Tags: versions, history

How can I check which versions on Ubuntu were previously installed on a system that has had multiple upgrades?  Like if it's on Ubuntu 22.04 now but has previously been on 18.04, 16.04, 14.04, 12.04, 10.04 et cetera.  How can I get a list of those that were historically installed on the system?

Comment: You need `etckeeper`

Comment: Why would you comment instead of adding an answer?  That's good to know

Comment: @b264 Converted to an answer.  Sorry, I was in a hurry when I wrote that comment.

Answer (score 3):

I have a desktop (used as a home server) that started as 16.04, was upgraded to 18.04, and then upgraded to 20.04

The history of that is captured in some log files, at least if you did it like I did (actually upgrading the system using the upgrade tools, not reinstalling)

- There's a folder in my /log directory called /installer; the files in there are dated 8/26/2016. If I look in the syslog in there, I can find a bunch of 16.04 references like `Get:1 cdrom://Lubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160720) xenial/main amd64 make amd64 4.1-6 [151 kB]`
- I upgraded to 18.04 in August of 2018. Sure enough, there's a log folder /dist-upgrade and in there is a folder /20180804-0802. If I look in main.log I find `INFO release-upgrader version '18.04.21' started`
- Similarly, I upgraded to 20.04 in October 2021. The main.log in the /dist-upgrade folder has a main.log dated 10/24/21 which contains the line `release-upgrader version '20.04.36' started`

So, at least for some paths through history, the info is in there if you do some digging.

Writing this up made me kinda sad that this will be that PC's last version of Ubuntu :(

Answer (score 2):

There should be log files in `/var/log/installer/` directory that should show the time the system was first setup / installed. Like on one of my systems here that has been a server shows in the `lsb-release` file that it was originally setup with 16.04.

Just something to help you along.

Comment: fantastic, thank you